# Do a HTTPResponse in PHP

Tags: php, cocoa, httpresponse

How I can make a HTTPResponse in php? I'm having some trouble :( I should read the response from a cocoa application. This is my php code:

```
<?php
HttpResponse::setCache(true);
HttpResponse::setContentType('text/plain');       
HttpResponse::setData("Some data");
HttpResponse::send();
?>
```

Then here is my Cocoa Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Web site"];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
        // create the connection with the request
        // and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self] autorelease];
    if (theConnection) {
        receivedData = [[[NSMutableData data] retain] autorelease];
        NSLog(@"OK!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@":(((");
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
        // Append the new data to receivedData.
        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    NSLog(@"DATA");
    NSString* aStr;
    aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",aStr);
}
```

But it doesn't work :( Ideas?

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't give us much to go on does it? Are you receiving error messages? If so, edit your question to show them. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httpresponse.php

Comment: It tell me this: Fatal error: Class 'HttpResponse' not found in /membri/istopped/asd.php on line 2

Comment: Have you made sure your system has HttpRequest? http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.requirements.php

Comment: Also see this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http library is not included with PHP by default as detailed on this page of the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php,  so you probably need to install it on your system.

The 'not found' error suggests that you haven't installed it yet, so you need to follow the steps in the instructions.

Also see here for more information http://php.net/http

Comment: Thanks ;) BTW At the end I've used print();